# 'no results' message not printing to screen

Tags: php, mysql

This query works, but does not display a 'no results' message. Should it be echo instead of exit on line 6?

```
<?php

    $key = $_GET['key'];
    $array = array();
    $con = mysql_connect("localhost","xxx","xxx");
    $db = mysql_select_db("xxx",$con);

    $query = mysql_query("select * FROM byartist2columns WHERE byartistnd LIKE '%{$key}%'");
    if( mysql_num_rows($query) == 0 ) exit( "No results" );
    while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
    {
        $array[] = $row['byartist'];
    }
    echo json_encode($array);

?>
```

`JAVASCRIPT`

```
<script> 
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('input.typeahead').typeahead({
        name: 'typeahead',
        remote: 'r-search.php?key=%QUERY',
        limit: 150
      });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Every time you use [the `mysql_`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php)
 database extension in new code
 **[a Kitten is strangled somewhere in the world](http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-zCT6jizimfI/UjJ5UTb_BeI/AAAAAAAACgg/AS6XCd6aNdg/s1600/luna_getting_strangled.jpg)** it is deprecated and has been for years and is gone for ever in PHP7.
If you are just learning PHP, spend your energies learning the `PDO` or `mysqli` database extensions and prepared statements.
[Start here](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)

Comment: What is $run?? I think it should be `mysql_num_rows($query)`

Comment: Thanks Yolo. That stopped it breaking, but it is not displaying the no results message

Comment: Try to be more specific: are you trying queries that you know for sure they should return 0 results? Then, what do you see? Any error messages? A blank screen?

Comment: yes. I'm deliberately searching for things that are not there and I would like the result to say 'no results'. Currently, it returns a blank results set

Comment: Try this in code `if( mysql_num_rows($query) == 0 ) {
$array[] = "no result";
  echo json_encode($array);
exit;
}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change condition as below.

```
if( mysql_num_rows($query) == 0 ) { $array[] = "No results"; }
```

Comment: Yes, they are proper! I thought (perhaps naively) that I should not publish them? But thanks - I'll try your ammendment

Comment: That slightly amended query works fine, but still no 'no results' message

Comment: check whether you receive `$key` as you expected.

Comment: Seems to be fine using $key

Comment: Edit this and check the output. `$db = mysql_select_db("xxx", $con) or die(mysql_error());`

Comment: Query works OK, still no 'No results' message if I search something that's not there